# Is it possible to use a later version of TFS Build than the server it connects to?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild

We have a TFS 2008 server used for source control, and a build agent connected to it that handles our continuous integration.

I'd like to be able to set up builds for projects that were created in a later version of Visual Studio, like 2012, whilst still being able to build projects that use Visual Studio 2008 (For example, we've some Windows Mobile code that we need to support)

Should this "just work"; do I need to install a separate build agent, or do I have to upgrade everything (and if so, for do I keep the Windows Mobile code building)?

Comment: Never had this scenario, but the projects are nothing else than MSBuild definitions. So building a VS2012 solution should work on TFS Build Agent 2008, if all frameworks and SDKs are installed on that machine. Simple said "If you can compile a solution in VS on the build server, the build agent should do so too".

Comment: @MikeR it's not so much a matter of build file compatibility with MSBuild but the build server's communication with the TFS server, which is versioned.

Comment: I know and he is using TFS2008, so he needs a 2008 Build Agent, but this agent can build VS2012 solutions if frameworks and SDKs are installed. The title is a bit misleading here I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was said you need to use the same version of the Build Agent as TFS (with the exception that TFS 2012 also supports 2010 build agents).

However, you can still install any version of Visual Studio supported by your build server OS.  So even though you are using 2008 Build Agent, you should be able to install Visual Studio 2012 and build projects with it.

Answer (score 0):

The build agent/controller needs to be of the same version as the TFS server itself - you can't just upgrade the build controller (wee tried this before upgrading from 2010 to 2012).

So, if I read the [compatibility matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997788.aspx) right, you will have to upgrade your environment.

Comment: but you can install Visual Studio 2012 on to the build agent and compile solutions using team build 2008. This is providing that the build agent is running on Windows 2008 or higher